# compiling java from within python

Tags: java, python, compilation, javac

I'm making an application where people can upload a java code and do stuff with it.

The application i'm making is in Python. I was wondering whether it was possible to call the 'javac' command from within python, in order to compile the uploaded java file

I'm also using JPype

Comment: So, where is your problem? Please post (as an edit to the question) what you are doing, and what the result (error messages and such) is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

But are you sure that allowing people to submit arbitrary code is a good idea? There are security aspects of that to consider...

Comment: The program runs on their own computer. So there's no risk in it for me

Comment: And that computer has network access? So someone can upload a java program that is an open proxy, or a web server that serves illegal content, or..

Comment: @Erik: I suppose this is a kind of applet, which will run on the client's computer (= the same one which uploaded the code). There is no new danger here - if someone bad can upload from a client, he already can execute stuff there.

Comment: Could i have a little bit of help? I don't immediately have an idea on how to use classpaths etc to get java working

Answer (score 0):

Entirely possible: just use the `system` command and invoke the java compiler. You'll probably need to set class paths and things of that nature, but it should work fine.

EDIT: see http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system and http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess for detail on invoking sub processes. You'll probably want to capture the output to return to the user in the event of a compile error.

Comment: `subprocess.call` is vastly superior to `os.system`.